# Update JObject with JToken

Tags: c#, json

Say I have some JSON

```
{
    "name": "John"
    ... other properties
}
```

It could also be like

```
{
    "person": {
        "name": "John"
    }        
    ... other properties
}
```

And this code to look for the name field.

```
var obj = JObject.Parse(json);
var token = obj.SelectToken("$..name");            
token = "James";
```

After getting it, I want to set it to another value and put it back into the JSON to get

```
{
    "person": {
        "name": "James"
    }        
    ... other properties
}
```

or

```
{
    "person": {
        "name": "James"
    }        
    ... other properties
}
```

How can I put the JToken back into the JObject?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
var o = JObject.Parse(json);
o["person"]["name"] = "James";
var backToJson = o.ToString(Formatting.None);
```

Comment: I don't know where in the JSON the name property is going to be so I can't do that.